# Drawing Routes on Map using MapKit based on current location

Tags: ios4, routes, mapkit

In my application i want to draw Routes based on the current location moving, For Example If i am starting at a point and while i am moving the current location also navigates with me, I have to draw route along the way i am moving.

I saw some sample applications but in those apps the Lat and Long values are hardcoded. How can i do this, I want to draw the route dynamically along the moving of current app. Please give me any idea.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple supplied a demo application called Breadcrumb with the 2010 WWDC Developer videos that does exactly this. You can get the sample code from here: http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/